# I have two dataframes DF1 and DF2, what is the best way to append rows that meet a conditional from DF2 to DF1 at specific indices?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to append a row from dataframe2 to dataframe1 at the end of each group in dataframe1, but only those rows from dataframe2 that match the column value in dataframe 1 (in this case: that match on 'Name').

If I have the dataframe1 given by:

```
data = {
    'Name':['Jill', 'Jill', 'Jill', 'Jill', 'Ryan',
            'Ryan','Lilian', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'Jack'],
    'Age': [15, 20, 25, 30, 23, 23, 45, 24, 65, 115]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

df1

data2 = {
        'Name':['Jack', 'Ryan',
            'Lilian', 'Jill'],
        'Gender': ['m', 'm', 'f', 'f']
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df2
```

I hope to see:

```
  Name   Age Gender
0 Jill   15  
1 Jill   20
2 Jill   25
3 Jill   30
4 Jill       f
5 Ryan   23
6 Ryan   23  
7 Ryan       m
8 Lilian 45
9 Lilian     f
10 Jack  24
11 Jack  65
12 Jack  115 
13 Jack      m
```

I have found the original indices for the last occurrence of groupby groups and put these into a list.

using `df1.index.values.tolist()`

Then was thinking about trying to setup some sort of loop that checks the name matches before appending at `index+1`.

Comment: `df1` cannot be replicated

Comment: `pd.concat([df1.set_index('Name'),df2.set_index('Name')]).sort_index().reset_index()`

Comment: `df1.append(df2).sort_values(by=['Name']).reset_index()`

Comment: Somehow I believe `df1.merge(df2, on='Name')` might work better for your purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
compare = df1.Name.unique()
df3 = df2[df2['Name'].isin(compare)]
df4 = df1.append(df3)
df5 = df4.sort_values(['Name','Age'])
df5 = df5.reset_index(drop=True)
print(df5)
```

Output:

```
      Age Gender    Name
0    24.0    NaN    Jack
1    65.0    NaN    Jack
2   115.0    NaN    Jack
3     NaN      m    Jack
4    15.0    NaN    Jill
5    20.0    NaN    Jill
6    25.0    NaN    Jill
7    30.0    NaN    Jill
8     NaN      f    Jill
9    45.0    NaN  Lilian
10    NaN      f  Lilian
11   23.0    NaN    Ryan
12   23.0    NaN    Ryan
13    NaN      m    Ryan
```